# How to execute iterective commands in the server without login into the server using python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

i have used paramiko to add user but **useradd** command works and **adduser** dosen't is there any way to provide all details that can be provided such as password,firstname,lastname,etc...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import paramiko
import subprocess
import os
import crypt
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('<hostname>', username='<username>', password='<password>', key_filename='<path/to/openssh-private-key-file>')
username = raw_input("enter the name : ")
a = stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command( "useradd " + username  )
while line == stdout.readlines():
    print (line)
ssh.close()
```

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: it adds user  but need with homedirectory and passwords need to be supplied

Comment: o sure, why not user -m flag to tell adduser to create a home dicrectory for that user and -p 'password' to define a password for the user, where password is password you want set to the user..., then your command looks like `adduser -m -p 'passwd' username`

Comment: adduser command is an iterative command which prompts user entry.

Comment: I'm sorry I got confused, it's not adduser but useradd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sudo adduser $username** is an interactive command you need to provide inputs to terminal. you can use this code:

This code will interact with targeted server's terminal in background and provide all the required inputs which is provided by user for

```
username = input("enter the name : ")
```

This is supplied as an input to be added as an user

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
output = ssh.connect('<$server-ip>', port='<$port>', username='$username',
                     key_filename="key/file/path")
username = input("enter the name : ")
command = f"sudo adduser {username}"
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
channel_data = str()
password = "$password_wants_to_assign"
complete = false
while True:
    if channel.recv_ready():
        channel_data = channel.recv(9999).decode("utf-8")
    else:
        continue

    if channel_data.endswith("hostname_of_targeted_server"):
        if not complete:
            channel.send(command)
            channel.send("\n")
            complete = True
        else:
            break
    elif channel_data.endswith("UNIX password: "):
        channel.send(password)
        channel.send('\n')
    elif channel_data.endswith("[]: "):
        channel.send('\n')
    elif channel_data.endswith("[Y/n] "):
        channel.send("Y\n")
ssh.close()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the user you used to login to the server has permission to create a new user?
You could try using **sudo** in your commands.